# Parse Query: return a value from the done() method in the class?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a problem with the following:

```
public int getPoints() {
    ParseQuery<RoyalPoints> pointsQuery = RoyalPoints.getQuery();
    pointsQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    pointsQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<RoyalPoints>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<RoyalPoints> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                i = 0;
                for (RoyalPoints obj : list) {
                    totalPoints = totalPoints + obj.getInt("points");
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("Points retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    return totalPoints;
}
```

I want to return the value totalPoints to use it in my MainActivity. I tried putting it in the method and having a void class instead but I can't find how to call it afterwards. Any idea how I can solve this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the findInBackground method when you don't want to find in the background. Use the find method instead:

```
  public int getPoints() {
      try {
         ParseQuery<RoyalPoints> pointsQuery = RoyalPoints.getQuery();
         pointsQuery.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
         List<RoyalPoints> list = pointsQuery.find();
         for (RoyalPoints obj : list) {
            totalPoints = totalPoints + obj.getInt("points");
         }

         return totalPoints;
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         Log.d("Points retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }
```

Note: Normally I would through the ParseException or convert to Runtime as the caller may need to do something with it.

Comment: Thank you so much ! How can i handle the parseException differently than with an if statement?

Comment: You could surround with a try/catch: try { ParseQuery<RoyalPoints> .... } catch {ParseException e } { Log.d("Points retrieval", "Error: " + e.getMessage());}

Comment: Have updated the original answer to handle the ParseException. I think it would be better to throw this as you probably need to do something with it..